# Salir de un for cuando se obtiene un GET 200 ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy solicitando a través de un bucle `for` una petición a una misma `URL` y dependiendo de la `KEY` obtengo código `429` o `200`

Mi pregunta es:

1.- no obtengo el `response.status`
2.- ¿Como logro salir del `for` cuando se encuentre con la primera respuesta 200?

Tengo algo como esto:

```
for (var i = 0; i < CLAVES.length; i++) {

        $.getJSON("CadenaPeticionURL&key="+CLAVES[i],function(response1){
            
            if (response1.status==200) {
               console.log(response1);
                return i;
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: ¿Sabias de que `$.getJSON` realiza una llamada ajax y por ende su respuesta es asíncrona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente sería así:

```js
text='';
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { break; }
  console.log('loop #'+i);
  text += i;
}

console.log('texto final: '+text);
```

pero la petición `$.get` es un objeto tipo "promesa", no se ejecuta de forma asíncrona porque se pausaría toda la aplicación hasta que el servidor responda.

Por ello lo que hace es darle una función:

```js
function(response1){
            
            if (response1.status==200) {
               console.log(response1);
                return i;
            }
```

Para que se ejecute al recibir los datos. Como tal al recibir los datos el *puntero o la línea de código ya está por fuera del ciclo for, por lo que no tiene sentido de que se salga.

Puedes comprobarlo si pones un console.log() al terminar el ciclo for, verás que se acabará primero y al final es que muestra la respuesta (no estando dentro del ciclo for).

Tienes dos opciones:

1. haces todas las peticiones en el ciclo y tomas el valor que llegó primero (apriori no sabes cual)

```js
let list=[];
var valores=[];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  list.push($.get(' https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+i,(result)=>{console.log('promesa individual: ',result.name);valores.push(result.name);}));
  
}

console.log('Mira que esta parte se ejecuta antes que la respuesta del servidor, ya ha salido del for-loop no tiene sentido salirse con break');

Promise.allSettled(list).then((values)=>console.log('cuando todas las promesas fueron cumplidas: ',valores[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Ejecutas una y esperas la respuesta, si falló intentas con la siguiente... y así. La forma que se me ha ocurrido es con recursividad.

```js
function recall(i){
$.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+i,(result)=>{console.log(`Promesa resuelta [i=${i}]: `+result.name);}).fail(function() {
console.log('hubo error en i = '+i);
if (i<10){
    recall(i+1)
    }
  });
  }

recall(-5);
console.log('Mira que esta parte que sigue se ejecuta antes que la parte de arriba');
recall(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```